# C in Ubuntu Linux - Cannot exec a forked process

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, fork, exec

I am attempting to write a simple C program in Ubuntu Linux that uses a couple processes to attach to shared memory and read/write data from/to it.  The general sequence is:

- Run process 1
- Process 1 allocates and connects to shared memory
- Process 1 forks into process 2
- Process 2 execs, passing "itself" the shared memory ID as a command line argument and running a new binary (`DP-2`) in the same directory
- Process 2 uses the shared memory ID to attach to shared memory

The `exec()` call is giving me trouble.  I have checked that process 1 allocates and connects to shared memory correctly, forks correctly, and that process 2 can connect to shared memory after being forked (from "within" process 1).  However, I cannot seem to get the `exec()` call to start the new program.  Instead, it just stops and eventually exits.

The total code is spread across several source files and has many debug statements, so I have only included the sections that handle the `fork()` and `exec()` calls.

Step 1: get the shared memory ID. `SHAREDBUFFER` here is the shared memory structure I am using.

```
shmID = shmget(shmkey, sizeof(SHAREDBUFFER), IPC_CREAT | 0660);
```

Step 2: put shared memory ID into a string array so that it can be passed to `exec()`.

```
char* argv[3] = {"Command-line", shmID, NULL};
```

Step 3: fork and check to see if this is the child process.  If so, exec the `DP-2` function with the command line arguments from step 2.

```
forkReturn = fork();

if (forkReturn == FORK_FAILURE) {
    // handle the failure
}
else if (forkReturn == IS_CHILD) {
    execvp("DP-2", argv);
    exit(0);
}
// other code for parent process
```

Additional notes:

- I know that `shmID` should be turned into a string when stored in `argv`.  I will be changing that as soon as I can.
- The `DP-2` program is currently a `hello world` program.  It can run without command line arguments, and I am pretty sure the problem should not lie from giving it an integer where it expects a c-string.
- I am aware that the different `exec()` functions have different purposes, but I believe `execvp()` should take what I have given it just fine.  I copied this particular usage from an online guide, but I don't really understand it that much.

Comment: Is `DP-2` in a directory in your PATH or is it in the same directory as your program? In the latter case: `./DP-2`

Comment: `DP-2` definitely needs to be `./DP-2`. Other than that if the problem persists please try adding a [mre].

Comment: Process 1 connects to shared memory before forking process 2, and process 2 is a  copy of process 1 after the fork and before the exec.  Therefore, before the exec, process 2 is already connected to the shared memory.  This makes your assertion 'and that process 2 can connect to shared memory after being forked (from "within" process 1)' of dubious value — it was already connected when you forked it.

Comment: You have `char* argv[3] = {"Command-line", shmID, NULL};` — but `shmID` is a number returned from `shmget()`.  You must convert it to a string and pass that string to the process.  Passing a typical integer as if it is a string runs into problems — the compiler should be shrieking at you, and you should not be ignoring it.

Comment: Note that if `DP-2` is in the same directory as the initial program (`DP-1`?), then using `execv()` instead of `execvp()` will execute the program in the current directory without any problem — it will ignore the value in `$PATH` and simply execute the named file.  This is likely a short-term workaround; you'll likely end up wanting to use `$PATH` to find the executables.  But it can be effective in the short term.  Also note that if you use `./DP-2`, the setting of `$PATH` will be ignored; if there's a slash in the name, it is a name relative to the current directory and `$PATH` is not used.

Comment: I have solved the issue.  It was a combination of:
1) using execv() instead of execvp(), 
2) changing shmID to a string using sprintf(), 
3) changing the name of the program to "./DP-2".

Thank you all very much.  This was aggravating, but I'm past it now.